# Linking CSS embeded image

Tags: css

For a webpage I used a div id that with css inserts a logo directly in the page.  I'd like that logo to be linked to (for instance) a homepage.  I can make it easily by doing this 
`<a href=xyz><div id=logo></div></a>`
of.course that doesn't validate (eventually DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict).

Can anyone suggest the (probably obvious) best practice?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do away with fiddly `SPAN` and `DIV` cluttering up your page and have the link itself be a block.

```
<a href="http://example.com/" id="logo">&nbsp;</a>
```

And in your CSS, style it with background and size it to the dimensions of the image you want to be clickable:

```
#logo
{
   background:url("/path/to/image.jpg");
   display:block;
   width:200px;
   height:80px;
}
```

Comment: I used class rather than id - I assume not to my detriment, but works fine and certainly more elegant than multiple spans - didn't need the css 'block' as I was using absolute positioning
Many thanks

Comment: Use `ID` if the element will appear once per page. Use `class` if it will appear more than once.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href=""><span></span></a>
```

Apply the background image, width, height and display:block to the span. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="something"><span class="logo"></span></a>`

You might have to declare `<span>` as `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a span:

```
<a href=xyz><span id=logo></span></a>
```

Don't forget to convert the span to a block element in your css:

```
.logo {
    display: block
}
```